# Drupal not detecting the correct version number of a module?

Tags: 7, updating

I am trying to transfer a site over, and run update.php.

Drupal is telling me that my system and menus modules are out of date. This is not the case - they're both up-to-date, in fact I downloaded the most recent ones and uploaded them to my public_html/sitename/modules folder.

Where is the version number stored, so that I can force Drupal to recognize that they are the correct module versions that Drupal is looking for?

Specifically for the menu and system modules.

This is in D7.

Comment: The module's .info file will have the version number...what does that say?

Comment: name = System
description = Handles general site configuration for administrators.
package = Core
version = VERSION
core = 7.x
files[] = system.archiver.inc
files[] = system.mail.inc
files[] = system.queue.inc
files[] = system.tar.inc
files[] = system.updater.inc
files[] = system.test
required = TRUE
configure = admin/config/system

; Information added by drupal.org packaging script on 2012-05-02
version = "7.14"
project = "drupal"
datestamp = "1335997555"

Comment: That's for the system module.

Comment: Yet I still have this: Error
 Unresolved dependency System (Version >7.10 required)
Administration menu requires this module and version. Currently using System version 7.4
Error
 Unresolved dependency System (Version >7.10 required)
Administration menu Toolbar style requires this module and version. Currently using System version 7.4

Comment: Have you cleared caches?

Comment: are the older versions still there in renamed directories?  if so that might explain what's going on, eg, drupal is seeing the older version in old_system/system.info instead of system/system.info

Comment: Like a specific Drupal cache (in one of the cache tables?) or just my browser cache (in this second case: yes. In the first: no)

I don't see any old_system folder.

Comment: @AndrewAlexander It would be the Drupal specific cache. Do you have Drush installed? If so issue a `drush cc all` command to the site. If not you might have to manually truncate the `cache_bootstrap` table for the changes to show

Comment: Or check admin/config/development/performance > "Clear all caches". And duplicate modules could be located anywhere, maybe even in your sites/all/modules folder (normally only for contributed modules). You can also download a new copy of Drupal core and only add your /sites folder in there.

Comment: I do not, and the site isn't available at all anyway, which is one of the reasons I am running the upgrade script.

Which row in the cache_bootstrap table should I delete? system_list?

Comment: You can truncate all cache_* tables - but don't drop the tables themselves.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Jimajamma in comment #2 pointed out it is worth to check whether there are older versions in renamed directories.

I had the same problem and error message with modules - after removing the backup below "sites/all/modules/old" the dependency check error in update.php was gone.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's related, but I had upgraded from drupal 7.27 to 7.31 and had an issue running update.php.  So u ran drush updb instead.

I still ran into problems with the version being listed as 7.27 when checking it with "drush status".  Turns out in the drupal root includes/bootstrap.inc there was a file that didn't cp over correctly.  In which sets variables that set the version in the app itself and for the drush command.

I also verified that the database had the correct information in the systems table.  Which was showing 7.31. : )

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on a D7 project that I took over.  I tried all of the following:

- update.php
- registry rebuild
- refreshing update status at /admin/reports/updates
- manually truncate cache_update

None of them worked.  In the end, this is what fixed it:

- I went into PHPMyAdmin
- opened up the system table
- Downloaded the BLOB from the 'system' module
- Manually amended the version from 7.67 to 7.69
- Edited the row in PHPMyAdmin then uploaded the amended BLOB

Finally the update status message is suppressed